# Brand new postgres setup - what to check first?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

My sys ops team have recently handed over a brand new set of postgres clusters (prod, stage, test etc). We don't have any DBAs and they are under resourced. Mistakes in config have been found before. I'm not a DBA but I understand database concepts and I am happy to do some learning in my own time.

My principle concern is whether I am getting the expected level of performance given the hardware deployed (its all on prem).

I know that different applications will see different performance based on their queries and the stats of the dataset etc, but at least I would like to verify that the hardware, OS and postgres have been correctly installed and configured.

Where should I start? Ideally I could run some perf tests and at least verify that all the instances perform similarly. Is there a set of standard performance tests that I could run?

Comment: "*Ideally I could run some perf tests*" - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html

Comment: Ok, I am able to run some tests using pgdump. But which test parameters is somewhat arbitrary and how to interpret the results? Is there a set of existing test results that I can compare against?

Comment: You interpret the results to see if your different environments deliver the same performance. As those are _your_ servers, obviously there is nothing you can compare that against.

Comment: Not even a rough order of magnitude? Eg, pgbench -c 10 -T 60, gives 10 / 100 / 1000 / 10000 TPS ?

Comment: One computer gives me `tps = 1721.781056` one gives me `tps = 656.818495` one gives me `tps = 492.373199` and one gives me `tps = 6942.873258`  - what does the tell you now?

Comment: Admittedly, not much. But they are all more than 10 and less than 10000, and that's something.